# Anaconda Launcher Failure in Win 10

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, launcher

I successfully used Anaconda 4.0.0 Launcher in Win 10 (64 bit). After not using it for several months, it stopped working: it would open and got stuck at the "Loading Application" screen

I removed it completely from the system and installed the newest version of Anaconda Launcher and it does not work either

Answer (score 0):

What version of Anaconda Navigator (as it is now known) are you using? Often when Navigator will not launch it is due to permissions issues. If you launch from the command line it will often provide a useful traceback that will help pinpoint the issue. Try running in your command prompt:

```
anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. One workaround is that I switched to an administrator account and reinstalled it, and then it works. But this workaround is not a satisfactory one since I could not launch the applications after switching back to a standard user account, although I chose to 'install for all users' when I installed it as the system admin. Some discussions about this could be found in [the project's Github repository](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1514)

Answer (score 0):

My solution may help you if you encountered a similar problem after win10 1089 update.

Here is my solution:

1. Go to **Control Panel**
2. Click **Uninstall a program**
3. Go through your programs, then find the following two programs:
   `Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 redistributable(x64)` and 
   `Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 redistributable(x86)`.

   Both should look like this image: [2015 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ0Ci.png)
4. If the number after "C++" is 2017, firstly uninstall both programs, and then install 2015 version of both.
5. Here is the official link of the 2015 version: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145